# Javascript function that takes a paragraph as an argument and returns an array of names

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I'm writing a function whose sole purpose is to take one paragraph as an argument.Then take all of the text that comes after a colon and split it at each comma.

Here is the function I came up with but the console is giving me a "Exception: TypeError: undefined is not a function"

here is the code in question:

```
function catNames (paragraph){
  return paragraph.indexof(":").slice(2).split(","); 
}

show(catNames("born 20/09/2004 (mother Yellow Bess): " +
          "Doctor Hobbles the 2nd, Noog"));
```

Comment: Do you have a function named `show`?

Comment: You have typos, `indexof` doesn't exist, but `indexOf` returns an index. Read up some more tutorials...

Comment: You can't slice a number, that's the main issue.

Comment: im slicing at position 2

Comment: show is a javascript method like consolelog

Comment: ah that typo would probably be the problem, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf(":")` function is return a integer and slice is method of array object. Therefore it throw an exception.

Comment: ah that makes sense, im doing a tutorial from the book eloquent javascript, and the code in question was what i created when i was asked to make a function that returns a paragraph at specific positions. I was wondering why my code threw an exception while the authors worked, when logically mine should have. I didn't know that indexOf returns an integer although that now makes perfect sense, thanks. thats why the author first created a var that held indexOf and then simply used it as a parameter of the slice method